# Automate aws Athena partition loading

Tags: amazon-athena

Athena's GUI has a table menu entry to "load partitions". What is the best way to automate the MSCK REPAIR TABLE command (either scheduled or triggered)?

I've seen this solution:
https://www.streamalert.io/athena-deploy.html

but it deals with a specific partition, instead of loading all available partitions automatically like the repair command.